# SyntaxError Line 18: TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python

Any idea of why this code is not allowing me to continue. I tried to enter this code on codeskulptor, but I am receiving issues on getting it to run.
**input[index] = classNum**

**TypeError: 'list' object is not callable.**

```
classes = [""] * (6)
input = [0] * (5)

yoga1 = 0
yoga2 = 0
child = 0
prenatal = 0
senior = 0
sIZE = 6
classes[1] = "Yoga1"
classes[2] = "Yoga2"
classes[3] = "Children's Yoga"
classes[4] = "Prenatal Yoga"
classes[5] = "Senior Yoga"
for index in range(0, 4 + 1, 1):
    print("Enter a class number")
    classNum = int(input())
    input[index] = classNum
    if input[index] == 1:
        yoga1 = yoga1 + 1
```

Comment: You have overwritten `input` in line 2 with a list.

Comment: What do you think is the value of `input` after `input = [0] * (5)`?

Comment: what do I need to change on that line?

Comment: classNum = int(input())

Comment: Yeah, just use a different variable name than “input”

Comment: hmm what should I use?

Comment: `input_list` would probably be good.

Comment: thank you. will try

Comment: any other suggestions? It will not allow me to put it in " _" that character

Comment: Please provide the entire error output.

Comment: TypeError: 'list' object is not callable.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because you've overwritten the name `input` with a list here:

```
input = [0] * (5)
```

You should give this variable a different name; you also don't need to pre-allocate the list to fill it in.  The entire snippet of code you posted can be replaced by:

```
classes = ["", "Yoga1", "Yoga2", "Children's Yoga", "Prenatal Yoga", "Senior Yoga"]
class_numbers = [int(input("Enter a class number: ")) for _ in range(5)]
yoga1 = sum(n == 1 for n in class_numbers)
```

Instead of creating variables `yoga1`, `yoga2`, etc to count up all the number of times a class number was entered, you could also create a dictionary for all the classes (going from name to count) with a dictionary comprehension like this:

```
class_counts = {
    name: sum(n == i for n in class_numbers) 
    for i, name in enumerate(classes) if name != ""
}
```

Or you could use the `collections.Counter` class, like this:

```
from collections import Counter

classes = ["", "Yoga1", "Yoga2", "Children's Yoga", "Prenatal Yoga", "Senior Yoga"]
num_counts = Counter(int(input("Enter a class number: ")) for _ in range(5))
name_counts = {classes[num]: count for num, count in num_counts.items()}
```

In this last example, `num_counts` tracks the number of times each class number was entered, and then you can combine that with `classes` to create `name_counts`, which tracks the same thing but in terms of the name of the class rather than its number.  `name_counts['Yoga1']` tells you the number of times `1` was entered as the class number, etc.

Comment: what is another name I should use instead of input?

Comment: Try running the example code I posted!  :)  In my example I'm using the name `class_numbers` because the list contains the numbers that correspond to the classes.